# I am getting null pointer exception when I an trying to putExtra from intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to call intent I set putExtra in first Activity as follows.
In first activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = getAdapterPosition();
    final Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(c, WhenCardClicked.class);
    intent.putExtra("title",titles[position]);
    intent.putExtra("desc",details[position]);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    c.startActivity(intent);
}
```

In WhenCardClicked.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_when_card_clicked);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc);
    String title ="";
    String desc = "";
    title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
    desc = getIntent().getExtras().getString("desc");
    Log.d("Debugtext", title+" "+desc);
    if(title != null)textView.setText(title);
}
```

In content_card_demo.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/title"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/desc"
android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>
```

I am calling intent in first activity. But I am getting

> Null pointer exceptioava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference at
>   quickbook.com.recyclerlayout.WhenCardClicked.onCreate(WhenCardClicked.java:28)

Comment: Some error log would be helpful

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at quickbook.com.recyclerlayout.WhenCardClicked.onCreate(WhenCardClicked.java:28)

Comment: Okay, the nullpointer is on one of your TextViews. Maybe because you setContentView to "activity_when_card_clicked" but the layouts name is "content_card_demo.xml". Coul dyou also provide the code of "activity_when_card_clicked.xml"

Comment: you put String Array. But WhenCardClicked.class, You getString. See it!

Comment: titles[position] is integer or string. Print Log and check your title value when you use get  extra

Comment: setContentView(R.layout. content_card_demo); in WhenCardClicked.class.
Try this

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. @G.K and @ Nguyễn Trung Hiếu

Comment: Can you also tell me where to get intent animation? I want like that in Google Keep. When the card is clicked, it should expand as intent.

Comment: @G.K. Post an answer and have Anjan mark it as accepted. To properly tag it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other people encoutering this:

> Okay, the nullpointer is on one of your TextViews. Maybe because you setContentView to "activity_when_card_clicked" but the layouts name is "content_card_demo.xml".

You just referenced the wrong layout in setContentView().